# Haw can I close notificationBar Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm stuck on notifatiionBar.I like to close it after he is shown.with icnon buton like this exemple

[primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/notificationBar.jsf#](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/notificationBar.jsf#)

```
<p:commandButton value="Enregistrer Parametre" action="#{optionBean.updateParametre()}" oncomplete="bar.show()" update="panel"/>
    <p:notificationBar position="top" effect="slide" widgetVar="bar" styleClass="top" >  
    <f:facet name="close">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/image/closebar.png" />  
        </f:facet>  
    <h:outputText value="Parametre Enregistre !" style="color:#FFCC00;font-size:36px;" />  
</p:notificationBar>
```

But I never get it works why ???

Comment: Do you have this images in your image folder?

Comment: yes .it is shwoing on another page but here in midel of notificationBar it is not showing

Comment: the notification bare is fixed now..I can close it .is there another solution .not like another button with hide() methode

Comment: I am note sure of any other solution.

Comment: the link is from primefaces site .notification bar is closed when I press the icon closebar from graphicalimage !!! I' try to do like this but ....

Answer (score 0):

it is working now , I add 2 script jquery   `bar.show();setTimeout(bar.hide(),10000)`

But the notification bar disappear quickly

```
 <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer Parametre" action="#{optionBean.updateParametre()}" oncomplete="bar.show();setTimeout(bar.hide(),10000)" update="panel"/>
        <p:notificationBar position="bottom" effect="fade" widgetVar="bar"  > 
        <f:facet name="close">  
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/image/closebar.png" />  
            </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="Parametre Enregistre !" style="color:#FFCC00;font-size:36px;" />  
    </p:notificationBar>
```

Comment: This should work as you want : `setTimeout("bar.hide()", 10000);` or `setTimeout("PF('bar').hide()", 10000);`.